# Python ModuleNotFound error, when calling python script in Laravel processes

Tags: python, laravel

I have developed a Laravel project and also have a python Script for the recommendation system. Python script works perfectly when I run it in any IDE like VS Code or CodeLab, but when I call this script in Laravel project using Laravel processes, then it throws an error that module Pandas not found and not also pandas but this is the same error showing with every module.
I have attached ScreenShots. please help me solve these errors.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the Code in which every module works good with codelab:

```
import advertools as adv
from rake_nltk import Rake
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faizanzafer/vnewsdemodata/main/news.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df)
```

This is the python script in which I have written some line just for test purpose to be called from laravel process:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import json
import pandas as pd
x=sys.argv[1]
data=pd.read_json(x)
print(data)
```

Here is the code part where I am calling that test script in Laravel:

```
$data2[] = [
    "id" => $gujrat["id"],
    "heading" => $gujrat["heading"]
];

$text = json_encode($data2);

$process = new Process(['python3', app_path() . "/Http/Controllers/nlp_test.py",$text]);
$process->run();
```

This the output where I get error for module not found.

> ================ Error Output: ================ Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/Users/faizanzafar/Downloads/vnews/app/Http/Controllers/nlp_test.py",
> line 5, in  import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'pandas'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered installing these modules on your system?

Comment: Yes I have installed all these modules and python script working perfectly on system but not with laravel